# seekp and seekg with fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

I have noticed this strange thing

```
fstream obj(filename , ios::in);
obj.seekp(7);
```

is the same as

```
fstream obj(filename , ios::in);
obj.seekg(7);
```

`seekg` and `seekp` do the same this and cause the same outcome, although i specified ios::in flag only

Why are they both work with fstream? And what is the difference between `seekp` and `seekg` with fstream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`basic_fstream` is derived from `basic_iostream` which is derived from `basic_istream` and `basic_ostream`. So, `basic_fstream` has function `seekp` from `basic_ostream` and function `seekg` from `basic_ifstream`.

**In short, in your case, calls to seekp and seekg do same actions, since actions perfomed by `basic_filebuf::seekpos` depends only on open mode for `basic_filebuf`.**

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& seekp(pos_type pos);
```

> Effects: If fail() != true, executes rdbuf()->pubseekpos(pos, ios_base::out). In case of failure,
> the function calls setstate(failbit) (which may throw ios_base::failure).

Where `pubseekpos` calls `seekpos` (which is `virtual`, so, calls `basic_filebuf::seekpos`)

```
pos_type seekpos(pos_type sp,
ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
```

> Alters the file position, if possible, to correspond to the position stored in sp (as described below).
> Altering the file position performs as follows:
>
> 1. if (om & ios_base::out) != 0, then update the output sequence and write any unshift sequence;
> 2. set the file position to sp;
>
> **3. if (om & ios_base::in) != 0, then update the input sequence;**
>
> where **om is the open mode passed to the last call to open()**. The operation fails if is_open() returns
> false.

Since you open file with `ios_base::in` function does 2 and 3 puncts.

```
basic_istream<charT,traits>& seekg(pos_type pos);
```

> Effects: Behaves as an unformatted input function (as described in 27.7.2.3, paragraph 1), except that
> the function first clears eofbit, it does not count the number of characters extracted, and it does not
> affect the value returned by subsequent calls to gcount(). After constructing a sentry object, if fail()
> != true, executes rdbuf()->pubseekpos(pos, ios_base::in). In case of failure, the function calls
> setstate(failbit) (which may throw ios_base::failure).